# How to Deny Access to No Referrer Requests on Multiste with Mapped domains

Tags: multisite, htaccess, spam, domain-mapping

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*yourdomain.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
```

I'm aware that the following code Denys Access to No Referrer Requests.

However I'm using a multiste installation and I would like to know.

How can I modify it so the code above to work with WP multiste and mapped domains?

Answer (score 2):

You could hook intop `pre_comment_on_post`:

```
add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', function(){
    if ( empty ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) )
        exit;
});
```

But … be aware, not all requests without an referer are actually spam posts. Some firewalls and proxies strip this field. And most automated spam comes with a `Referer` field filled with the name of the spammed domain. So you will get many false positives.

Comment: it's better than touching `.htaccess` and it's true you get a lot of positives with this method of spam detecting

Comment: Is there any sold/better way to approach this for Multiste to reduce the false positives?